# Python error Inconsistent intendation detected

Tags: python, csv, replace

I'm fiddeling with a python script for replacing some characters in a specific column of a tab seperated text file.

If I run the script I get the Error: Inconsistent intendation detected.

```
import csv
# File names: to read in from and read out to
input_file = "test.txt"
output_file = input_file + "-SA_input.txt"

with open(input_file) as to_read:
with open(output_file, "wb") as tmp_file:
    reader = csv.reader(to_read, delimiter = "\t")
    writer = csv.writer(tmp_file)

    desired_column = [1]        # text column

    for row in reader:     # read one row at a time
        myColumn = row[desired_column]   # build the output row (process)
        myColumn.replace('0', ' ')
        myColumn.replace('1', ' ')
        myColumn.replace('2', ' ')
        myColumn.replace('3', ' ')
        myColumn.replace('4', ' ')
        myColumn.replace('5', ' ')
        myColumn.replace('6', ' ')
        myColumn.replace('7', ' ')
        myColumn.replace('8', ' ')
        myColumn.replace('9', ' ')

        writer.writerow(row) # write it
```

Help is much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
with open(input_file) as to_read:
with open(output_file, "wb") as tmp_file:
```

you need to use

```
with open(input_file) as to_read:
    with open(output_file, "wb") as tmp_file:
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an indentation error and you have mixed spaces and tabs. Always use tabs to indent.